# Python function replacing itself in the module namespace

Tags: python

I'm reading through some of Werkzeug's source and stumbled upon this nugget in the werkzeug.wrappers module.

```
def _run_wsgi_app(*args):
    """This function replaces itself to ensure that the test module is not
    imported unless required.  DO NOT USE!
    """
    global _run_wsgi_app
    from werkzeug.test import run_wsgi_app as _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
```

What are the fine prints of doing something like this? What's the difference between this definition and another without the `global _run_wsgi_app` statement?

Comment: The `import` statement binds to a name too; in this function the `from werkzeug.test import run_wsgi_app as _run_wsgi_app` would bind to a local name, except for the `global` making the import bind a global name instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go without the `global` statement, you will be creating a local variable with the name `_run_wsgi_app`, and then will use it, but nothing will change in the global namespace. Using `global _run_wsgi_app` you ensure that you are re-binding the global name to the new function.

Remember the basic usage of `global`:

```
def foo():
    x = 2
def bar():
    global x
    x = 3

x = 1
print(x) # --> 1
foo()
print(x) # --> 1
bar()
print(x) # --> 3
```

Your example is the same, but instead of binding the name directly with `name = ...`, it does with `from ... import ... as name`.

An alternative way to redefine itself without `global` is to use the module object where it is contained.

```
def _run_wsgi_app(*args):
    from werkzeug.test import run_wsgi_app as new_run_wsgi_app
    import sys
    sys.modules[__name__]._run_wsgi_app = new_run_wsgi_app
    return new_run_wsgi_app(*args)
```